# How to use StopWatch multiple times in C#?

Tags: c#, optimization, time

I have  short code that performs different operations and I want to measure the time that takes to perform each. I read here about Stopwatch class, and wanted to optimize my time measurements.
my functions calls 5 other functions and I want to measure each without declaring :

```
stopwatch sw1 = new stopwatch();
stopwatch sw2 = new stopwatch();
etc..
```

my function looks like that:

```
public bool func()
{
 ....
 func1()
 func2()
 ....
 ....
 func5()
}
```

is there any way to measure the time using one stopwatch instance?

thanks!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use **delegates** to pass a method as a parameter to a function.

Here I used Action Delegates as the methods specified does not return a value.

You can modify it accordingly if your method has a return type or parameter by using a **Function delegate**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method 1 Time Elapsed (ms): {0}", TimeMethod(Method1));
        Console.WriteLine("Method 2 Time Elapsed (ms): {0}", TimeMethod(Method2));
    }

    static long TimeMethod(Action methodToTime)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        methodToTime();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    static void Method1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    static void Method2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

By using this you could pass any method you want.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 14):

What you need is the *Restart* function of the *Stopwatch* class, something like this:

```
public bool func()
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    func1();

    Debug.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    stopwatch.Restart();

    func5();

    Debug.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, try this:

```
    void func1()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        func1();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.Write(sw.Elapsed);

        sw.Restart();
        func2();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.Write(sw.Elapsed);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any difference between writing sw.Restart and sw.Start in this case?

Comment: Use Restart to stop current interval measurement and start a new interval measurement (MSDN).  Restart will clear the elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this little class:

```
public class PolyStopwatch
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, long> counters;

    readonly Stopwatch stopwatch;

    string currentLabel;

    public PolyStopwatch()
    {
        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        counters = new Dictionary<string, long>();
    }

    public void Start(string label)
    {
        if (currentLabel != null) Stop();

        currentLabel = label;
        if (!counters.ContainsKey(label))
            counters.Add(label, 0);
        stopwatch.Restart();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (currentLabel == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No counter started");

        stopwatch.Stop();
        counters[currentLabel] += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        currentLabel = null;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        if (currentLabel != null) Stop();

        long totalTime = counters.Values.Sum();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, long> kvp in counters)
            Debug.Print("{0,-40}: {1,8:N0} ms ({2:P})", kvp.Key, kvp.Value, (double) kvp.Value / totalTime);
        Debug.WriteLine(new string('-', 62));
        Debug.Print("{0,-40}: {1,8:N0} ms", "Total time", totalTime);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var ps = new PolyStopwatch();

ps.Start("Method1");
Method1();
ps.Stop();

// other code...

ps.Start("Method2");
Method2();
ps.Stop();

ps.Print();
```

If calls follow each other, you can omit the Stop()

```
ps.Start("Method1");
Method1();
ps.Start("Method2");
Method2();
ps.Print();
```

It works well with a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    ps.Start("Method1");
    Method1();
    ps.Start("Method2");
    Method2();
}
ps.Print();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
void MyFunc()
    {
        Watcher watcher = new Watcher();
        //Some call
        HightLoadFunc();
        watcher.Tick("My high load tick 1");

        SecondFunc();
        watcher.Tick("Second tick");

        Debug.WriteLine(watcher.Result());
        //Total: 0.8343141s; My high load tick 1: 0.4168064s; Second tick: 0.0010215s;
    }
```

Class

```
class Watcher
{
    DateTime start;
    DateTime endTime;

    List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>> times = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>>();

    public Watcher()
    {
        start = DateTime.Now;
        times.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>(start, "start"));
        endTime = start;
    }

    public void Tick(string message)
    {
        times.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>(DateTime.Now, message));
    }

    public void End()
    {
        endTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public string Result(bool useNewLine = false)
    {
        string result = "";
        if (endTime == start)
            endTime = DateTime.Now;

        var total = (endTime - start).TotalSeconds;
        result = $"Total: {total}s;";

        if (times.Count <2)
            return result + " Not another times.";
        else 
            for(int i=1; i<times.Count; i++)
            {
                if (useNewLine) result += Environment.NewLine;
                var time = (times[i].Key - times[i - 1].Key).TotalSeconds;
                var m = times[i];
                result += $" {m.Value}: {time}s;";
            }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great approach!